# Axis2.jar conflict in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, apache-axis

I have a problem deploying an Axis 2 web application. I'm using Jboss 4.2.0, that already has a web application that makes use of an Axis 2 client. This Axis 2 application that I'm trying to deploy is actually an archive service (with an .aar extension), which is put inside the "services" folder in the Axis 2 web application. The latter is then built using an ant builder, and the resulting .war file is what I'm deploying. Now when I remove the older application from Jboss' deploy folder, my new application works just fine. But when I redeploy the old application again, I get the following exception from Jboss:

```
13:58:44,382 INFO  [AxisServlet] org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing
13:58:44,383 ERROR [[/axis2]] Servlet /axis2 threw load() exception
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.engageModule(AxisConfiguration.java:464)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.engageGlobalModules(AxisConfiguration.java:591)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.engageModules(DeploymentEngine.java:615)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.engageGlobalModules(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:301)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:81)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:516)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:436)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4069)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4373)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:761)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:553)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5310)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:301)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
        at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
        at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
        at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor138.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy45.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
        at org.jboss.ws.integration.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy46.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.loop(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:274)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.run(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:225)
```

My guess is that Jboss is conflicting between the axis2-1.4.1.jar file that exists within the .ear of the older application, and the axis2.jar of the Axis 2 web application that I'm trying to deploy. Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. My initial assumption was correct: My problem was that when deploying the .ear project first which contains the axis2-1.4.1.jar jar file, the classloader of the application was registering itself as the classloader that's capable of loading all the classes that are found in the .jar file, since no other classloader is able to serve those classes. ( you could check the following links for more clarifications:
1">http://thorgull.be/doku.php?id=tutorials:jboss:classloaderisolation#fnt_1
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossClassLoadingUseCases
)

To solve the problem, I have created a jboss-app.xml file (Since it's a .ear project), and added the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <jboss-app>
  <loader-repository>
   mypackage:loader="myapplication.ear"
  </loader-repository>
 </jboss-app>
```

With this change, a separate child repository will be created for my .ear application (This is called isolated mode). This will fix any problems that someone might encounter from having different versions of the same packages/classes, trying to run on the same instance of Jboss.

Another solution that might be easier but doesn't offer much control on what applications to isolate and which ones should delegate to the root repository of packages/classes is by modifying the ear-deployer.xml (Found in your deploy folder), and setting the following XML element:

```
<attribute name="Isolated">false</attribute>
```

to **true**.

Make sure to read the references that I have included in my post, to better understand how classloaders work.

Good luck.